# Navbar and bootstrap problems

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am new to twitter-bootstrap, all I want to do is to change the `navbar` so it has no `borders` or `padding` and when you hover optional links to highlight a different `background color`. I also want to have a `margin-left` and `margin-right` of about 10px which I can't get working?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"             href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100|Luckiest+Guy|Quicksand:300|Asap:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Roboto|Signika:700" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>

<style>

.navbar-default {   
 border: 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: #00a3fe;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;font-size: 14pt;font-weight: 800;width: 100%; valign: middle;color : #ffffff;

 }

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
color: #ffffff;
 }

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
color: #ffffff;
}
</style>


<nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">

   <div class = "navbar-header">
  <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
     data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
     <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">Company</a>
</div>

<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="non-active"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="non-active"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="non-active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a>    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where have you written the css for adding margin-left and margin-right of 10px ?

Answer (score 1):

You css is being overwritten by bootstrap. use `.navbar.navbar-default` instead of just `.navbar-default` to give your css preference.

To have a margin round your `nav`, wrap a dive aound it and give that div `padding:0 20px;` that way your `nav` will have 20px space on the left and right. (I have given that div `class="navbarcon"` you can look up the css for it)

To change background of link on hover use `:hover` pseudo class. I have set the background green here and when you hover over them , it changes to red.

```css
body,html{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navbarcon{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 20px;
  background-color: #00a3fe;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {   
 border: 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: #00a3fe;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14pt;
 font-weight: 800;
 width: 100%;
 valign: middle;
 color : #ffffff;
 }

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
color: #ffffff;
background-color:green;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
color: #ffffff;
background-color:green;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a:hover {
background-color:red;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbarcon">
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
   <div class = "navbar-header">
  <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
     data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
     <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">Company</a>
</div>

<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: good answer, but i would like the menu a the top to have the same background colour not white like in your example? its just a spacing i thought?

Comment: Thankyou, but i want the the spacing to be the same same blue colour, its just a margin basically isnt it? its white in your example.

Comment: ok. I updated my answer and  you have the same color spacing now. But I didn't understand your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use css hover effects. Learn about it here [w3schools css hover](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)
hope this helps!